# How to minify or increase the speed of laravel 8 blade templates?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I want to minify the HTML generated by the laravel 8 blade files.
I have tried
https://github.com/renatomarinho/laravel-page-speed
and
https://github.com/vrkansagara/LaraOutPress

but both are not working.
https://github.com/renatomarinho/laravel-page-speed
this is giving me javascript error i.e no-js files are being loaded.
**error code = failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403**

and
https://github.com/vrkansagara/LaraOutPress this one is giving an error like some $app is missing.

Comment: Your question is full of links and unclear. Please provide more detail in your question so that we can understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Did you try `php artisan view:cache`? Much faster than that you won't get. Unless you use server compression (gzip) but that has nothing to do with Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

To minify HTML:

Install [voku/html-min](https://github.com/voku/HtmlMin):

```bash
composer require voku/html-min
```

Put this in the `boot` method in `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider`:

```php
Blade::directive('minifyhtml', function () {
    return '<?php ob_start(); ?>';
});

Blade::directive('endminifyhtml', function () {
    return '<?php $htmlMin = new \voku\helper\HtmlMin(); $html = ob_get_clean(); echo $htmlMin->minify($html); ?>';
});
```

Add the directives in your Blade files like so:

```php
@minifyhtml
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
@endminifyhtml
```